# Как сделать чтобы массив, введенный в main, сортировался в bubbleSort?

Tags: java

Делаю первые шаги в Java, изучаю чужой код. С двух разных источников скопировал код. Как сделать чтобы массив, введенный в main, сортировался в bubbleSort?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Sort180820 
{
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Объявляем Scanner
            System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
            int size = input.nextInt(); // Читаем с клавиатуры размер массива и записываем в size
            int array[] = new int[size]; // Создаём массив int размером в size
            System.out.println("Insert array elements:");
            /*Пройдёмся по всему массиву, заполняя его*/
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = input.nextInt(); // Заполняем массив элементами, введёнными с клавиатуры
            }
            System.out.print ("Inserted array elements:");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                System.out.print (" " + array[i]); // Выводим на экран, полученный массив
            }
            System.out.println();
          
        }
        public static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {
          boolean sorted = false;
          int temp;
          while(!sorted) {
            sorted = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++) {
                if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
                    temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i+1];
                    array[i+1] = temp;
                    sorted = false; 
                }
            }
        
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того что во время изучения не мешайте источники в одном задании. Не то у вас будет получаться Франкенштейн из за не понимания кодов.

Ответ на ваш вопрос.

Добавьте после

```
System.out.println();
```

Следующий код

```
bubbleSort( array);
System.out.print ("Sorted array elements:");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      System.out.print (" " + array[i]); // Выводим на экран, полученный массив
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // Объявляем Scanner
    System.out.println("Enter array length: ");
    int size = input.nextInt(); // Читаем с клавиатуры размер массива и записываем в size
    int[] array = new int[size]; // Создаём массив int размером в size
    System.out.println("Insert array elements:");
    /*Пройдёмся по всему массиву, заполняя его*/
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array[i] = input.nextInt(); // Заполняем массив элементами, введёнными с клавиатуры
    }
    System.out.print("Inserted array elements:");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i]); // Выводим на экран, полученный массив
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bubbleSort(array)));

}

public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    boolean sorted = false;
    int temp;
    while (!sorted) {
        sorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = temp;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }

    }
    return array;
}
```